# Is data inside mapreduce partitions sorted, if yes, how does it happen?

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, shuffle, partition

Is data inside mapreduce partitions sorted, if yes, how? AFAIK, it is grouped on the basis of the key. If it internally sorts, wouldn't it be an overhead to sort all the data inside all the partitions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the input splits that the mappers receive as input, then no; they are not sorted, as this would indeed create an unnecessary overhead.

Sorting starts right **before** the end of the map phase (only if a reducer is used), so the input of the reduce function is sorted. The criteria that specify which reducer will handle the output of the mappers is defined by the *Partitioner*. The HashPartitioner (the implementation of Partitioner that is used by default) hashes the output keys of the mappers and sends them to the reducer corresponding to a specific hash value (so here is when **grouping** takes place).

*Sorting* is actually the second process of the reduce phase, after *shuffling* a.k.a. *copying* (i.e. getting the output of the mappers) and before actually running the *reduce* function and it is based on the keys. It can be thought of as a merge-sort like process, which merges the sorted output of the mappers.

You can find much more details on Tom White's book 'Hadoop: The Definitive Guide'. Here is a schematic approach of what I described:

[image]

Comment: True, but while different spills are being merged into a on-disk file(s) (before the shuffling phase begins), are the merged outputs sorted as well? If they are, how?

Comment: Also, since you mentioned " which merges the **sorted** output of the mappers", doesn't it imply that there is some kind of sorting happening right when the spills are being merged? Will it be right to say that grouping is actually 'grouping-cum-sorting'?

Comment: Yes, the merged output of each mapper is also sorted, using merge-sort. The key has to implement the WritableComparable class, which specifies how the keys will be compared. This is true only when a reducer is used. When 0 reducers are used, then the output is not sorted and the map output is written directly to disk.

Comment: I changed the phrase "Sorting starts **at** the end of the map phase" to "Sorting starts **right before** the end of the map phase" to make it more clear.

Comment: Isn't that an overhead to run sorting on all the map outputs, even though just grouping might have worked. The reducer outputs will anyhow be sorted.

Comment: Sorting takes place on **each** mapper's output separately, not **all** mappers' output. The reducer outputs are **not** sorted.